# how variables or labels are equal to numbers?

Tags: assembly, memory, cpu, ram

`mov db[0x402000],10`can give us some clue how`var: db 10`works then when we write `mov bx,var`the memory address goes to bx.
the questions is how a label or variable like 'var' is equal to a memory address and how computer take them as equal value? or in an easy way how computers equal a variable like x to a number like 2 at a low level then we can use in our code? where will these data store?

Answer (score 3):

I think you wanted to say `mov byte[0x402000], 10`. Actually, computers do not deal with labels or variables; assemblers and linkers deal with them. They hold the offset or memory locations of their values to abstract memory things to the user. If the code is assembled as binary, they are disappeared. Or they can be kept inside the symbol table for relocation or debugging purposes.

Answer (score 2):

> ... how a label or variable like 'var' is equal to a memory address ...

In some semiconductor memory (like a RAM), all memory cells (in the case of x86: bytes) have an address. An address is nothing but a number identifying that memory cell.

So if the CPU wants to read the variable `var`, it must send the address (number) of the cell containing the variable `var` to the RAM chip and the RAM will send the value stored in that cell back to the CPU.

Writing to the variable is similar: The CPU sends the address and the new value to the chip.

> ... and how computer take them as equal value?

As already said in the other answer, the computer does not know about the variable.

Some executable file (for example `.exe` under Windows) does not contain any "variables". If you compile some C or C++ program, the following steps are done:

- The C/C++ program contains a variable `char var;`
- The compiler creates some assembly file from the C/C++ program.
  Assembly language does not know about "variables"; `var: db 10` does not mean: "*a one-byte variable named `var` with the value 10*", but it means: "*one byte of RAM named `var` containing the value 10*".
  So the assembly file does already no longer contain variables but it already contains information about bytes in RAM.
- The assembler creates some object file from the assembler file.
  The assembler typically groups multiple RAM cells in so-called "sections"; so if the original C file contained 100 `char` variables, the object file does not contain 100 single RAM cells but it contains one "section" of 100 bytes length.
  In the object file the instruction `mov [var],al` becomes `mov [0],al` and there is some information that the `[0]` was originally `[var]` in the assembly file.
- Then the linker creates the executable (`.exe` under Windows) file from one or more object files.
  The linker will assign memory addresses to each "section" mentioned in the object files. In the simplest case it will start at some address (e.g. 0x402000) and place the first section of one object file to that address. If that section is 0x234 bytes long, it will place the next section to the address 0x402000 + 0x234 = 0x402234 and so on...
  The object file contains some information about where the memory cell `var` is located. Let's say the information says that the memory cell `var` is the 10th byte of the second section. This means that the memory cell is located at the address 0x402234 + 9 = 0x40223D. Using the information that `[0]` was `[var]` in the assembly file, the linker replaces the value `0` (in `mov [0],al`) by `0x40223D`.

As a result of this 3-step process (compiler, assembler, linker) no variables or names remain in the program but only numeric addresses.